# React abort/cancel AJAX request. Axios or XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I just develop a SPA and need help with the asynchronous requests I send by react componentDidMount to my server side (node). The queries work, but if I change quickly to the different pages, the setState functions within the ajax response are still running. Although the components are unmounted.

> Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means
>   you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
>   Please check the code for the undefined component.

To avoid this error, I would like to abort/cancel the request which I send on componentWillUnmount if this is the correct way to do this.

I tried this with xml and with axios but it doesnt work. I hope you have a working example for me. Iam open for other request methods like fetch or something.

The code looks something like this (Axios), but it doesn't cancel the request:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

let CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let source = CancelToken.source();

class MakeAjaxRequest extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const that = this;

    axios.get('/user/12345', {
      cancelToken: source.token
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        if (axios.isCancel(response)) {
          console.log('Request canceled', response);
        } else {
          that.setState({
            data: response.data
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (thrown) {
        if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
          console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
        } else {
          // handle error
        }
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
  }

  //....other stuff, like render the data
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Axios has the option of cancelling requests:

https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

Another way of preventing setState from firing on some kind of callback after the component is unmounted is to have a local boolean variable storing whether or not the component is mounted, i.e.

```
componentDidMount(){
   this._mounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   this._mounted = false;
}
```

Then in the axios callback check whether `_mounted` is true before trying to call `setState()`

Comment: Thank you Jayce444. Can you tell me why componentWillUnmount() {
    source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
  } doesnt work correctly and how i should build this component?

Comment: Yeah based on your code it seems to match the axios documentation. Not sure why it isn't working, maybe something to do with the reference to `this` in the callback. Check that you've got the latest major release of axios. I assume you've ensured that `componentWillUnmount` is actually firing when you think it is. And if so, maybe try the other technique to see if that works, since that relies on the same method. Sorry can't be of more help :(